# Not receiving notifications from Amazon S3 Put events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have two buckets created (bucket1 bucket2) and two SNS notification topics (alert_bkp_1 and alert_bkp_2) created and configured in the S3 event property.

Setup is for receiving email alerts whenever a Put occurs inside the bucket.

I'm encountering two problems with this setting:

**Bucket 1**

Bucket1 receives .tar files of 4 servers within a scheduled backup window in the servers crontab, but I receive email notifications of only 3.

Details:

- When I send manually I get notification of all 4 servers normally.
- The 4 backups are being stored diary in the bucket normally.

**Bucket 2**

Bucket 2 is receiving the .dump type backup files normally, but does not receive the email notifications.

Detail:

- When I send manually I get notification of the 2 servers normally.
- The 2 backups are being stored diary in the bucket normally.

I have already made several changes in the configuration of events of S3, but without success, I do not know what to do, someone would have any tips to help me with this problem?

Comment: It might help to post screenshots of how the events are setup in S3, whiting out any sensitive data.

Comment: My first thought is that the event type you are notifying on is happening for some uploaded objects but not others. A common issue here is to configure for s3:ObjectCreated:Put and then find that large objects actually cause s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload. Which event type(s) have you configured?